# Find biggest value in Java

Tags: java, find, compare

For an input like the following is it ok to use `Float.compare` to find the biggest float in an array?

```
Float[] v = {0.38118651972530804, 0.3580139606405057, 0.7358862700995704};
float max = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++)
    if (Float.compare(max,v[i]) > 0) max = v[i];
```

Is there a better way? or maybe there could be some precision error?

Comment: Is it possible to change type? i.e. `BigDecimal`?

Comment: I can do that, what would change if we do it?

Comment: No point in using BigDecimal unless you need absolute control of your numbers (e.g. you're dealing with currency). In this simple of a case, you ought to just write `if(v[i] > max)` also, you might want to initialize max to `Float.MAX_VALUE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about one line:

```
Float max = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(v));
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a collection and call the max() method. See: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)

Answer (score 0):

There can be errors if all the values in the array are less than -1. Better to initialize max as v[0].

And, your code finds the smallest element. Not the largest element.

```
Float[] v = {0.38118651972530804, 0.3580139606405057, 0.7358862700995704};
float max = v[0];

for (int i = 1; i < v.length; i++)
    if (Float.compare(max, v[i]) < 0) max = v[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this-

```
float max = v[0]; // the first item in array

// Loop through all items starting the second one
for (int i = 1; i < v.length; i++)
{
     if (v[i] > max) // If current item is bigger, update max to current item
     {
      max = v[i];
     }
}
```